# Delphi Firemonkey TListview - Header does not show if it is repetition

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

[image]

Delphi 10.4 running on Windows 64, Android shows the same issue.  I don't think it's a bug, but more a setting issue (I just can't find a setting)

If I have consecutive items whose Header is the same text, firemonkey version of TListView does not display the second item.

I can only find NativeOptions.Grouped=False, which is the closest thing I can find in terms of setting. Whether set to true/false made no difference.

Any pointers?  Attached below is a Minimal Working Example, which demo the issue.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Button1: TButton;
    FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable;
    BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
    FDMemTable1CustomerID: TIntegerField;
    FDMemTable1CustomerName: TStringField;
    BindSourceDB2: TBindSourceDB;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLinkFillControlToField : TLinkFillControlToField;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with FDMemTable1 do
  begin
    Open;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 1;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'ABC';
    Post;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 2;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'XYZ';
    Post;

    Append;
    FieldByName('CustomerID').AsInteger := 3;
    FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := 'XYZ';
    Post;
  end;

  if not Assigned(FLinkFillControlToField) then
  begin
    FLinkFillControlToField := TLinkFillControlToField.Create(BindingsList1);
    FLinkFillControlToField.Control := listview1;

    with FLinkFillControlToField do
    begin
      Category := 'Quick Bindings';
      Track := False;
      Direction := linkDataToControl;
      AutoActivate := False;
      AutoFill := True;
      BindSourceDB1.DataSource.Enabled := True;
      FillDataSource := BindSourceDB1;
    end;
  end;

  with FLinkFillControlToField do
  begin
    FillHeaderFieldName := 'CustomerName';

    with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
    begin
      SourceMemberName := 'CustomerID';
      ControlMemberName := 'Text1';
    end;
    with FillExpressions.AddExpression do
    begin
      SourceMemberName := 'CustomerName';
      ControlMemberName := 'Text2';
    end;
  end;
  FLinkFillControlToField.Active := True;
end;


object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 404
  ClientWidth = 763
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object ListView1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    Position.X = 16.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 561.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 353.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.Width = 223.000000000000000000
        Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
      end
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text2'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
        Appearance.Width = 208.000000000000000000
        Appearance.Height = 44.000000000000000000
        Appearance.PlaceOffset.X = 326.000000000000000000
      end>
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
      item
        AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
        AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
      end>
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 592.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 57.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object FDMemTable1: TFDMemTable
    FetchOptions.AssignedValues = [evMode]
    FetchOptions.Mode = fmAll
    ResourceOptions.AssignedValues = [rvSilentMode]
    ResourceOptions.SilentMode = True
    UpdateOptions.AssignedValues = [uvCheckRequired, uvAutoCommitUpdates]
    UpdateOptions.CheckRequired = False
    UpdateOptions.AutoCommitUpdates = True
    Left = 576
    Top = 128
    object FDMemTable1CustomerID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'CustomerID'
    end
    object FDMemTable1CustomerName: TStringField
      FieldName = 'CustomerName'
      Size = 30
    end
  end
  object BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 576
    Top = 192
  end
  object BindSourceDB2: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = FDMemTable1
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 576
    Top = 248
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 20
    Top = 5
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you write a minimal program reproducing the issue you have? Then edit your question to add that program source (.pas and .fmx). By the way, which platform are you using (Windows, Android...)? And wich Delphi version.

Comment: @fpiette, I've posted a minimal example.  Windows32/64. android also same issue.  Delphi 10.4.  Previously I didn't post an example because I did not think it was a bug... it seems more like a setting issue.  If the immediate subsequent header is different, then the header displays.  If not, it disappears.

Comment: I tested you code and it seems to be OK: I see 'ABC' header with record 1 and "XYZ" header with records 2 and 3. Please add a screen dump of what you get and draw an arrow showing what is wrong on it. I used Delphi 10.4.1 and made your code in a Windows application.

Comment: what I mean is that I'd like record 3 to have its own XYZ header. (see original post with screen capture)

Comment: I have the exact same result as you. Are you sure that what you need is not a simple grid?

Comment: @fpiette, no, I'd need TListview as the application is more complex. but I'd just like the header to repeat in the 3rd row instead of being hidden when the header is the same.

Comment: I must be stupid because I don't seen clearly what you want if it is not a grid. Please use the screen dump you showed, edit it to looks like what you need and add this in the question as well. Use another color to draw missing information. You can use the good old Windows Paint to do that.

Comment: @fpiette apologies I wasn't clear. I've now updated it so that the XYZ in red is the line I'd like the Listview to show, but it is not showing as any repeats of Headers is not shown in TListview.

Comment: Using object inspector, set TextAlign of  ListView1 item 'Text1'  to Leading and that item will be right under the header. Then in your code, bind Text1 to CustomerName and bind Text2 to CustomerID. Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: @fpiette, this is not what I want. I want the Header text to appear every single row.  Right now Header text only appears for 2 out of 3 rows.

Comment: OK, then once more, change the screen dump, the one with XYZ in red with EXACTLY what you want. Really EXACTLY! The header must be CustomerName, and the left AND right columns also?!

Comment: I've updated it. Hope this is very clear now.  It's just simply missing another header in Row 3.  Row 3 Header is missing.  Row 1 and Row 2 are displaying.

Comment: @fpiette, just wondering if there is any chance of overriding any methods that is hiding the 'repeated' header.

Comment: Why didn't you update EXACTLY the screen dump?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by 'screen dump'? do you mean screen capture? this is the exact screen capture - RED is what I need additional.  Blue is the words in explanation.

Comment: @fpiette thanks for trying. appreciate the effort taken to reply to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that Headers are designed to work that way - it does not repeat if the consecutive header is exactly the same.

So I just moved the text into the 'main' section, so that it will repeat for every record.

Thanks for trying to help through your replies.

Comment: oh, I didn't know that's what you meant previously... I thought you meant use a stringgrid or something previously. thanks.